# Understanding options to sort

Tags: sort, options

#### part 1

```
ps -e | sort -k 1 -nr
```

What is the interpretation of the above command? I want to understand the role of `-nr`. It is not clearly given the man pages of sort.

#### part 2

When you open the man page of head, one of the options states:

> `-c`, `--bytes=[-]K`
>
> print the first K bytes of each file; with the leading `-', print all but the last K bytes of each file

How to interpret the `-c, --bytes=[-]K`?

Comment: When you have two single letter options (`-n` and `-r`) that do not take arguments, usually you can squish them together like `-nr`. Check the man page for the individual options. An example: `ls -ltr` or `ls -l -t -r`

Comment: related, but not dupplicate : http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/193815/how-do-i-use-man-pages-to-learn-how-to-use-commands/193816#193816

Comment: The `K` in the manpage is schematic for a number. You can have `-c10` or `--bytes=10` to print the first 10 bytes of the file. Or `-c-10`/`--bytes=-10` to print all but the last 10 bytes of the file.

Answer (score 2):

**Part 1**

1. `ps` is a command that reports a snapshot of the current processes, and the `-e` argument specifies `ps` to report all processes.
2. `|` is a pipe. This allows you to redirect the output of the previous command into another command. In this example, you are redirecting the output of `ps -e` to `sort`.
3. `sort` is a command that allows you to sort the lines from stdin. The `-k 1` argument sorts via a key, in this case `1`. This means that you are going to sort with respect to the first column of `ps -e`, the PID numbers. The `-nr` argument sorts the input numerically in reverse (descending) order.
4. NOTE: The `-n` argument is actually redundant in this implementation. You do not need it because you are already specifying `sort` to sort by the first column. `ps -e | grep -rk 1` will work just the same.

**Part 2**

1. The `-c` or `--bytes=[-]K` argument allows you to print out the first or all but the last X kilobytes of a file, where X is how kilobytes you want to print. To print the first X kilobytes, just put a number after `-c`. To print all but the last kilobytes, add a `-` in front of the X kilobytes.
2. Also note that, with `-c`, you do not need to specify a number followed by `K`. This syntax is only needed in the `--bytes=` argument.

Comment: The `--bytes=...` option also only takes a number argument, not an argument followed by a literal `K`. The `K` in the manpage is meant to stand in for a number, schematically.

Answer (score 0):

Part 1: `-n` is for numerical sorting, `-r` is for reverse sorting, so `-nr` combined sorts in descending order numerically.

Part 2: you can use either `-c` (short option) or `--bytes=` (long option, more typing but no difference). So say `--bytes=-1024` for the last 1024 bytes for instance.

Comment: You do not interpret the meaning of all commands and arguments present in this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, the items between the brackets `[]` can be interpreted as 'optional'.  So `--bytes=[-]K` means you can use a 'dash' for 'the last of...' and without it to mean 'the beginning of ...'.  Since the 'K' is not within the brackets, it means that it is required for the option `--bytes`