# LFTP Script to Download Files

Tags: scripting, ftp, lftp

I want to write a lftp script that will download files every 15 minutes from a server every x amount of time.

Can someone advise how i can do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**First:** Create a script. You can call it whatever you want. I will call it `downloader.sh`.

```
#!/bin/bash
PROTOCOL="ftp"
URL="server.example.com" 
LOCALDIR="/home/user/downloads"
REMOTEDIR="dir/remote/server/"
USER="user"
PASS="password"
REGEX="*.txt"
LOG="/home/user/script.log"

cd $LOCALDIR
if [  ! $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "$(date "+%d/%m/%Y-%T") Cant cd to $LOCALDIR. Please make sure this local directory is valid" >> $LOG
fi

lftp  $PROTOCOL://$URL <<- DOWNLOAD
    user $USER "$PASS"
    cd $REMOTEDIR
    mget -E $REGEX
DOWNLOAD

if [ ! $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "$(date "+%d/%m/%Y-%T") Cant download files. Make sure the credentials and server information are correct" >> $LOG
fi
```

**Second**: Add it to crontab. If you want to execute it every exact 15 minutes inside an hour:

```
45,30,15,00 * * * * /home/user/downloader.sh >/dev/null 2>&1
```

If you want to execute it each 15 minutes no matter what is the starting minute:

```
*/15 * * * * /home/user/downloader.sh >/dev/null 2>&1
```

**Explaining the variables:**

- `PROTOCOL` - What protocol to use. `lftp` supports a good range of them: `ftp, ftps, http, https, hftp, fish, sftp` and `file`. https and ftps require lftp to be compiled with OpenSSL or GNU TLS support.
- `URL`- Name or IP of the server. You can even add `:PORT` at the end if your server doesn't use the default port of the protocol being used.
- `LOCALDIR` - Where to save the files.
- `REMOTEDIR` - Where to `cd` on the remote server to get the files.
- `USER` and `PASSWORD` - ftp credentials.
- `REGEX` - Regular expression to filter files to download. It can be useful if you want to download only files of a determined extension, for example. Use `*` if you want to download everything.
- `LOG` - Logfile location.

**Explaining some code logic:**

**1.** - if

```
if [  ! $? -eq 0 ]; then
fi
```

The `$?` variable is a special bash variable that means "status code of last command". Bash always return zero on successful command executions so, comparing `-eq` (equal to) with the starting `!` (negative) on an `if` should be enough to see if `cd` and `lftp` had issues during execution. If you want a better log of what happened, you will have to crawl through those commands' documentation.

**2.** - heredocs

```
lftp  $PROTOCOL://$URL <<- DOWNLOAD
DOWNLOAD
```

[bash heredocs](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html). It's a way to say "feed this command with this input list". I've named the limit string `DOWNLOAD` so, everything between `<<- DOWNLOAD` and `DOWNLOAD` will be input to `lftp`. You will see examples on the internet with `<<` symbol but I prefer the `<<-` version since it supports indentation.

**3.** - lftp commands

```
    user $USER "$PASS"
    cd $REMOTEDIR
    mget -E $REGEX
```

These are internal commands of `lftp` that means respectively, auth the user with `$USER` login and `"$PASS"` password, change to `$REMOTEDIR` and bulk download anything with the `$REGEX` keywords. You can learn them by simply typing `lftp`, and as soon as an lftp shell is opened, type `?` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> or `? lftp-command-you-want` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Example:

```
[root@host ~]# lftp
lftp :~> ?
    !<shell-command>                     (commands)                           alias [<name> [<value>]]
    attach [PID]                         bookmark [SUBCMD]                    cache [SUBCMD]
    cat [-b] <files>                     cd <rdir>                            chmod [OPTS] mode file...
    close [-a]                           [re]cls [opts] [path/][pattern]      debug [<level>|off] [-o <file>]
    du [options] <dirs>                  exit [<code>|bg]                     get [OPTS] <rfile> [-o <lfile>]
    glob [OPTS] <cmd> <args>             help [<cmd>]                         history -w file|-r file|-c|-l [cnt]
    jobs [-v] [<job_no...>]              kill all|<job_no>                    lcd <ldir>
    lftp [OPTS] <site>                   ln [-s] <file1> <file2>              ls [<args>]
    mget [OPTS] <files>                  mirror [OPTS] [remote [local]]       mkdir [-p] <dirs>
    module name [args]                   more <files>                         mput [OPTS] <files>
    mrm <files>                          mv <file1> <file2>                   [re]nlist [<args>]
    open [OPTS] <site>                   pget [OPTS] <rfile> [-o <lfile>]     put [OPTS] <lfile> [-o <rfile>]
    pwd [-p]                             queue [OPTS] [<cmd>]                 quote <cmd>
    repeat [OPTS] [delay] [command]      rm [-r] [-f] <files>                 rmdir [-f] <dirs>
    scache [<session_no>]                set [OPT] [<var> [<val>]]            site <site-cmd>
    source <file>                        torrent [-O <dir>] <file|URL>...     user <user|URL> [<pass>]
    wait [<jobno>]                       zcat <files>                         zmore <files>

lftp :~> ? mget
Usage: mget [OPTS] <files>
Gets selected files with expanded wildcards
 -c  continue, resume transfer
 -d  create directories the same as in file names and get the
     files into them instead of current directory
 -E  delete remote files after successful transfer
 -a  use ascii mode (binary is the default)
 -O <base> specifies base directory or URL where files should be placed
```

The knowledge related to know that `mget` would be the right command inside `lftp` came from [reading manpages](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/193815/34720) and searching for keywords like "bulk", "multi" or "mass", and knowing that the [`ftp(1)`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ftp) command also have the `mget` command so, probably `lftp` would have an equivalent.

**Manpage:** [`lftp(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/lftp)

Comment: Thanks for this. Is there any way i can log to a .txt file what is happening when this runs?

Comment: sure - either log it internally to the script, or change the tail end of the cron job from ">/dev/null 2>&1" to "> /some/log/file 2>&1" (or separately pipe stderr elsewhere)

Comment: Since i did this script in a rush, i will add some logging inside of it.

Comment: @nwildner I've been looking around the internet to see what the `-dt` operator means in your control-flow conditions, but I can't find an answer. Care to explain?

Comment: @nwildner: I’ve never heard of a `-dt` operator in bash.  My copy doesn’t recognize it.  But, most importantly, the document you linked to doesn’t mention it. Are you using a non-English version of bash?  Are you translating the “different than” operator from your version of bash into English (manually, rather than checking what the English version of bash actually supports)?

Comment: Stupid mnemonic my head created the date i first posted this question. My script is using the negative of `-eq` so, i was incorrect. Edited the answer.