# LFTP Script to Download Files and then move them to a remote directory

Tags: scripting, ftp, lftp

I found the following
[LFTP Script to Download Files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/254841/lftp-script-to-download-files).
The script will fit, but currently it deletes the files after successful transfer.
But I want the files to be moved to another directory (e.g. backup) on the remote server after the transfer.
I searched but did not find a parameter for the mmv command.

Can someone tell me how to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't see anywhere in that script where anything is deleted. `mmv` is the right command to use to move the remote files afterwards; what  exactly have you tried and what happened instead of what you wanted?

Answer (score 1):

**0. Manual of mget**

`lftp :~> ? mget`

- -c  continue, resume transfer
- -d  create directories the same as in file names and get the
  files into them instead of current directory
- **-E  delete remote files after successful transfer**
  ....

---

**1. DELETED REMOTE FILE**

The problem of deleted remoted file at option **-E** :

`mget -E $REGEX` change it to `mget $REGEX`

**2. MOVE FILE**

`mv` command to rename file

`mmv` command to move file

If there problem with moving, it usualy because credentials,
like fileA.txt (made by userA), Folder_Backup_B(made by userB),
but you move fileA.txt to Folder_Backup_B and get `mmv: Access failed: 550 Rename failed.`
mmv need same user (or power user like root) that create / copy / move

In my test I have Directory :
**Remote Directory**

- /home/tyacode/test_ftp *#REMOTE_DIR*
- /home/tyacode/backup *#REMOTE_BACKUP_DIR*

When use lftp, I can't access backup folder from source /home, So I modify variable :

```
REMOTE_DIR="/home/tyacode/test_ftp/"
REMOTE_BACKUP_DIR="../backup/"
```

Maybe different scenario if you use hosting ftp

---

**3. MODIFIED SCRIPT**

```
#!/bin/bash
PROTOCOL="ftp"
URL="server.example.com"
USER="user"
PASS="password"
REGEX="*.txt"
LOG="/home/user/downloads/script.log"
LOCAL_DIR="/home/user/downloads"
REMOTE_DIR="dir/remote/server/file_directory"
REMOTE_BACKUP_DIR="dir/remote/server/backup_directory"

cd $LOCAL_DIR
if [  ! $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "$(date "+%d/%m/%Y-%T") Cant cd to $LOCAL_DIR. Please make sure this local directory is valid" >> $LOG
fi

lftp  $PROTOCOL://$URL <<- DOWNLOAD
    user $USER "$PASS"
    cd $REMOTE_DIR
    mget $REGEX
    mmv $REGEX $REMOTE_BACKUP_DIR 
DOWNLOAD

if [ ! $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "$(date "+%d/%m/%Y-%T") Cant download files. Make sure the credentials and server information are correct" >> $LOG
fi
```