# Linux man: How do you "see ld.so(8)"?

Tags: linux, man

I have read the [Wikipedia man page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man_page), [this StackExchange page](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/193815/how-do-i-use-man-pages-to-learn-how-to-use-commands), and the `man` section of [Unix and Linux System Administration Handbook, 4th edition, page 16](https://books.google.com/books?id=0SIdBAAAQBAJ&lpg=PA16&ots=xmJWaF1j5f&dq=%22because%20they%20are%20read%20with%20the%20man%22&pg=PA16#v=onepage&q=%22because%20they%20are%20read%20with%20the%20man%22&f=false), but they don't seem to explain how to use man to, as `man ldd` says:

> ...(see ld.so(8))

These commands fail:

```bsh
man 8 ld      # No manual entry for ld in section 8
man 8 ld.so   # No manual entry for ld.so in section 8
man ld.so(8)  # -bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

Which command displays the man page for ld.so(8)?

Details:

```bsh
$ cat /etc/redhat-release
CentOS Linux release 7.4.1708 (Core)

$ yum list installed man-pages
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, versionlock
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
Error: No matching Packages to list
```

Comment: see it here: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld.so.8.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be the correct command

```
# man 8 ld.so
```

but your system does not seem to have installed the manual.

```
# sudo yum install man-pages
```

should do the trick, since

```
# rpm -qf /usr/share/man/man8/ld.so.8.gz
man-pages-3.53-5.el7.noarch
```

I will check it (on CentOS 7, too):

```
# man 8 ld.so | wc
241    1997   15690
```

*What else could go wrong?*

*Man section 8 not searched*: `man` searches the manual sections given in the `MANSECT` environment variable, if that is set.  If it does not contain `8` then section 8 of the manual pages will be ignored.  Unset the variable and try again.

*Repository faulty*
You could download from here: http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/Packages/ and install by hand and/or check your `/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo` file.

Comment: If you still have problems check your environment variables for a variable called `MANSECT` and unset the variable, then test again.